# C++ replacement for BYTE C macro

Tags: c++, c

I'm trying to port the C openGL texture loading code found here:
 http://www.nullterminator.net/gltexture.html
to C++. In particular I'm trying to deal with reading some textures in from a file, what is the best way of rewriting the following code in an idiomatic and portable manner:

```
GLuint texture;
int width = 256, height = 256;
BYTE * data;
FILE * file;

// open texture data
file = fopen( filename, "rb" );
if ( file == NULL ) return 0;

// allocate buffer
data = malloc( width * height * 3 );

// read texture data
fread( data, width * height * 3, 1, file );
fclose( file );
```

In particular what is the best way of replacing the BYTE macro in a c++ way that is portable?

EDIT: BYTE macro is not defined in the current environment I am working in. I was trying to figure out what the underlying type of this is on other systems so that I can typedef for the correct type.

Comment: What does the macro expand to? Why can't you just use that? From the looks of it BYTE*, its just char* or unsigned char*

Comment: On this particular system it seems as though BYTE is not defined. Also I'd rather not leave the code as-is as we are trying to keep to a coding standard that is exclusively c++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The C code should work just fine when compiled as C++.

Rather than use the `BYTE` type, just use the OpenGL-defined type `GLbyte`, which is the actual type the APIs take anyway.  It is defined in `gl.h` thus:

```
typedef signed char GLbyte;
```

A very quick (untested!) translation of the above code into C++ would be something like:

```
GLuint texture;
unsigned width = 256, height = 256;
unsigned buffer_size = width * height * 3;
GLbyte * data;
std::ifstream file;

// open texture data
file.open(filename, ios_base::in | ios_base::binary);
if (!file) return 0;

// allocate buffer
data = new BYTE[buffer_size];

// read texture data
file.read(data, buffer_size);
file.close();

// Process data...
// ...

// Don't forget to release it when you're done!
delete [] data;
```

Comment: Ah great, GLbyte looks like exactly the thing I need!

Comment: With a few cleanups this almost works but it gets to following compiler error: `error: invalid conversion from ‘GLbyte*’ to ‘std::basic_istream<char>::char_type*’ [-fpermissive]` . This is from the line `file.read(data, buffer_size);`

Comment: It's most likely a signed/unsigned issue.  In this case, you can add a cast to hush the compiler, as you're treating it as a block of binary data.  In C++, a `static_cast<char*>(data)` would be more idiomatic I think.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the original code is portable, you can just leave it. Just make sure you pull in the definition of `BYTE` as is. C++ compilers are backwards compatible to C, so the corresponding headers are still there.

(If `BYTE` is really a macro, I'd perhaps `typedef` it.)

Comment: On this system BYTE is not defined.

Comment: So get the definition on the old system and see if you can integrate it. If you don't want to break any code, you need the same setup here.

Answer (score 0):

BYTE* in this case seems to be just a macro for char* or unsigned char*. I could be wrong but I doubt it. So using char* or unsigned char* in your program would be equivalent. However if you are porting from C to C++ you might want to consider using ifstream (in binary mode) from the C++ standard library.

Answer (score 0):

Use `unsigned char` instead of `BYTE` - should work as expected (you might have to cast the return value of `malloc()`.